# Running Regressions for unique Values

Tags: arrays, vba, loops, regression

I'm doing a project to find out the effects of various factors on my University's course bidding prices.

To do this, I have to run regressions of the y-variable, Bids, against individual x-variables (Prof A, Prof B, Prof C...) for each column as shown below.

I have written some code to run regressions for all bid prices of all modules, but the trouble is it has to be mod specific, ie the bid prices for ACCT101, ACCT102, ACCT103... must be regressed together.

I believe this uses a scripting dictionary which is out of my depth. Any help would be welcome!!

DATA:

[Example of my Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKeag.png)

CURRENT CODE:

```
Sub RegressionRunner()

Dim rng As Range
Dim column As Range
Dim i As Variant

Set rng = Range("C1:G1")

For Each column In rng.Columns

column.End(xlUp).Select

Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress", ActiveSheet.Range("$B$1:$B$40"), _
ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)), _
False, True, 95, ActiveSheet.Range("J$1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(3, 0), _
False, False, False, False, , False

Next column

End Sub
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: If it's true [regression analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis#Underlying_assumptions) that you're after, this question may be better suited to [https://math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/) to figure out the mathematics before trying to tackle coding.  Is the end goal to report on how course enrollment is affected by each professor?  If so, it seems fairly straightforward (give each course/professor combination a score based on share of enrollment, and then total...)

Comment: Do you mean the bid prices for ACCT101 must be run together? Then the same for ACCT102 etc......